# how to extend Swift Dictionary of where K:String and V:String

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I was thinking the following syntax:

```
extension Dictionary where Key:String,Value:String{
    func addIfNew(key:String,value:String){
      print("new item added: \(key) with value: \(value)")
    }
}
```

For example: the function would log any new added data

Answer (score 15):

This should be enough ...

```
protocol P {}
extension String: P {}
extension Dictionary where Key:P, Value:P {
    func addIfNew(key:String, value:String){
        print("new item added: \(key) with value: \(value)")
    }
}

let d:[String:String] = [:]
```

don't make other types conforming to P and you are fine

in Swift3

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == String {
    func addIfNew(key:String, value:String){
        print("new item added: \(key) with value: \(value)")
    }
}
let d:[String:String] = [:]
d.addIfNew(key: "a", value: "A")
```

Comment: `key` and `value` should be of type `Key` and `Value`, but other than that, if it works, great! It isn't any different from my `StringType` except that `StringType` is much more expressive than `P`

Comment: @RMenke the trick is define key and value parameters as String type. If you try to call the function with something else, compiler complain. So this is, by my own meaning, the best way if you would like make an extension when exact types are required for key value pair.

Answer (score 7):

Not possible the way you want to do it. You can only constrain `extensions` of `Dictionary` to `protocols` `Key` and/or `Value` conform too. Else you will just get more errors.

But you can do this :

```
extension String : CustomStringConvertible {

    public var description : String { return self }

}

extension Dictionary where Key : CustomStringConvertible, Value : CustomStringConvertible {
    func addIfNew(key:Key,value:Value){
        print("new item added: \(key.description) with value: \(value.description)")
    }
}

var dict : [String:String] = [:]
dict["blah"] = "foo"
dict.addIfNew("blah", value: "foo2")
```

---

Important is to ask yourself what you want.

- Only allow this function on `Strings`
- Anything that is `Equatable` is good enough

If `Equatable` is good enough you can do this :

```
extension Dictionary where Value : Equatable {
    mutating func addIfNew(key:Key,value:Value){

        if self.values.contains(value) {
            print("\(value) exists")
        } else {
            print("new item added: \(key) with value: \(value)")
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}

var dict : [String:String] = [:]
dict["blah"] = "foo"
dict.addIfNew("blah1", value: "foo2")
dict.addIfNew("blah2", value: "foo2")
```

Although this function will work on any `Dictionary` whose `Value` is `Equatable`, you can choose to only use it on those that have `String` as `Value`

---

If you really need it to only work on `String` you need to create a custom `protocol` and only have `String` conform to it. The `protocol` will need to have a computed property that returns `self` because else you will not be able to `print` it, since it isn't considered a `String` inside the `extension`.

```
protocol StringType : Hashable {

    var value : String { get }

}

extension String : StringType {

    var value : String { return self }

}

extension Dictionary where Key : StringType, Value : StringType {
    mutating func addIfNew(key:Key,value:Value){

        if self.values.contains(value) {
            print("\(value.value) exists")
        } else {
            print("new item added: \(key.value) with value: \(value.value)")
            self[key] = value
        }
    }
}

var dict : [String:String] = [:]
dict["blah"] = "foo"
dict.addIfNew("blah1", value: "foo2")
dict.addIfNew("blah2", value: "foo2")
```

---

Side note:

Since `Dictionary` is a `struct` functions need to be `mutating` in order to alter `self`.

Comment: Why not using `StringLiteralConvertible` directly instead of custom protocols?

Comment: @EridB Because `StringLiteralConvertible` does not constrain the function to just `String`

Comment: It could be great if you provide some more info like this on the answer, also explaining the mutating function considering also other users who will come and see this question. Other than that this is a good answer +1